# Azure DevOps Server 2019: Custom Dashboard Widget not available

Tags: azure-devops

We have a **self-hosted Azure DevOps Server 2019** for which I have created my own widget using the tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-dashboard-widget?view=azure-devops-2019.
I was also able to successfully add the extension to the server and the extension is also visible.
However, when I edit my dashboard, my newly created widget is not displayed. What could be the reason for this?

Furthermore, I also installed the extension VstsDashboardWidgetProjectTemplate (https://github.com/GregTrevellick/VstsDashboardWidgetProjectTemplate) in Visual Studio and also created an extension/widget from it. Unfortunately with the same result that I can install and see the extension, but not the actual widget.

I am attaching the vss-extension.json file as I suspect this is where the error is most likely to be found. However, I can also supply the other files if needed.

```
{
    "manifestVersion": 1,
    "id": "MyVeryFirstCustomExtension",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "name": "My Very First Custom Extension",
    "description": "Samples containing different widgets extending dashboards",
    "publisher": "MyCompany",
    "categories": [
        "Azure Boards"
    ],
    "targets": [
        {
            "id": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services"
        }
    ],
    "icons": {
        "default": "img/logo.png"
    },
    "contributions": [
        {
            "id": "HelloWorldWidget",
            "type": "ms.vss-dashboards-web.widget",
            "targets": [
                "ms.vss-dashboards-web.widget-catalog"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "name": "Hello World Widget",
                "description": "My first widget",
                "catalogIconUrl": "img/CatalogIcon.png",
                "previewImageUrl": "img/preview.png",
                "uri": "hello-world.html",
                "supportedSizes": [
                    {
                        "rowSpan": 1,
                        "columnSpan": 2
                    }
                ],
                "supportedScopes": [
                    "project_team"
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "files": [
        {
            "path": "hello-world.html",
            "addressable": true
        },
        {
            "path": "sdk/scripts",
            "addressable": true
        },
        {
            "path": "img",
            "addressable": true
        }
    ],
    "scopes": [
        "vso.work"
    ]
}
```